# Не получается настроить NTP для работы с GPS модулем в качестве источника синхронизации (NMEA+PPS)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gps, ntp

Не могу настроить NTP на Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Linux 4.15.0-74-generic). В качестве источника синхронизации хочу использовать NMEA + PPS модуля GPS.

Сам модуль GPS подключен через USB, с использованием преобразователя интерфейсов SILABS CP2102:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

К линии DCD преобразователя подключен сигнал PPS GPS приемника. С получением данных NMEA и работе с ними в NTP проблем не возникает. Проблема возникла с использованием сигнала PPS. 
Делаю ldattach PPS /dev/ttyUSB0:

```
[ 1815.641450] pps_ldisc: PPS line discipline registered
[ 1815.641812] pps pps0: new PPS source usbserial2
[ 1815.641820] pps pps0: source "/dev/ttyUSB0" added
```

В /dev появляется соответствующий нод pps0. Вроде бы всё хорошо, вот только не работает.

```
ppswatch /dev/pps0
trying PPS source "/dev/pps0"
found PPS source "/dev/pps0"
time_pps_fetch() error -1 (Connection timed out)
time_pps_fetch() error -1 (Connection timed out)
```

Соответственно и сам NTP не видит сигнал PPS. В ядре вроде поддержка включена:

```
# HSI clients
#
CONFIG_HSI_CHAR=m
CONFIG_PPS=m
# CONFIG_PPS_DEBUG is not set

#
# PPS clients support
#
# CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_KTIMER is not set
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_LDISC=m
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_PARPORT=m
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_GPIO=m
```

pps_ldisc после ldattach подгрузился:

```
lsmod|grep pps
pps_ldisc              16384  1
pps_core               20480  2 pps_ldisc,ptp
```

Кто сталкивался? Подскажите, куда копать?

Answer (score -1):

На сколько я знаю, PPS сигнал не может передаваться по USB интерфейсу, поэтому он нго и не видит.

Comment: Да не, может, это обычный dcd по факту. А то, что это usb, знает только драйвер от cp2102, в нем и проблема. Я его немного "поковырял", дописал функционал получения сигнала dcd из потока данных и соответствующим образом настроил саму микруху cp2102, в итоге заработал ppswatch, но за сам ntp так и не зацепился. Разбираться дальше было некогда, поэтому в боевую версию устройства заложил ftdi ft232, с ним всё работает без проблем.